# if cell a1=text then cell a2=bold. How do i do it in excel?

Tags: excel, vba

if cell a1 is equal to some text then i want to select the corresponding cell in the same row to be in bold and italic. for eg if there is text "james" in cell a1 then i want to make the other cell a2, containing an integer, in bold and italic. This has to be done for a selective range in the worksheet, so wherever there is james i need the corresponding cell to be bold and italic. Please help me out here.

Answer (score 2):

Your Google term is [conditional formatting](http://www.contextures.com/xlcondformat02.html).

Answer (score 1):

did you try simple conditional formatting?

in 2007 :
Conditional Formatting --> new rule --> Use a formula to determine which cells to format

formula : `=IF(A1="james",TRUE,FALSE)"`
where "james" would of course better be replace by a reference to a cell.

Answer (score 1):

1. Select cell b1
2. On the Home tab, in the Style group, click Conditional Formatting, click New Rule...
3. select "Use a formula to determine which cells to format"
4. Set the formula to =A1="james". Take Tom's advice and make "james" a cell reference.
5. Click the Format... button, select Font Style "Bold Italic" and click OK
6. Click Ok to close the New Formatting Rule dialog
7. you should still have cell b1 selected
8. On the Home tab, in the Style group, click Conditional Formatting, Manage Rules...
9. Find the rule you just created and change its "Applies to" from =$B$1 to =B1. This makes the "applies to" reference relative rather than fixed (that's what the $ is doing) in order for copy and paste to automagically change your formulas to the destination row/column.
10. click OK
11. Copy and paste cell b1 to the other cells in the b column.

I hope this helps!